# NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT legacy driver on 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 20.04, mac

I am running 20.04.1 on kubuntu x86_64 bit, but having problems installing "NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT" on 5.4.0-42-generic@macPro1.1.

I tried with `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137.run`.

Ends with

```
  43   │ make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modbuiltin obj=fs/configfs
  44   │ make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modbuiltin obj=arch/x86/entry/vdso
  45   │ /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic/tools/build/Makefile.build:37: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic/tools/build/Build.include: Datoteka ali imenik s tem imenom ne obstaja
  46   │ make[6]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic/tools/build/Build.include'.  Stop.
  47   │ make[5]: *** [Makefile:43: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
  48   │ make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic/tools/build/Makefile.include:5: fixdep] Error 2
  49   │ make[3]: *** [Makefile:67: objtool] Error 2
  50   │ make[2]: *** [Makefile:1835: tools/objtool] Error 2
  51   │ make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  52   │ make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modbuiltin obj=fs/crypto
  53   │ (for m in fs/configfs/configfs.ko; do echo $m; done;    \
```

#### EDIT

I do not want to use nouveau module because it flickers. After installing nvidia-331 there is no success. My 7300 GT is listed [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/legacy-gpu/)

Comment: Why aren't you using the provided nvidia drivers? Usually they work better in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I know but major release numbers of those drivers in default repository are from 390 to 440.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was problem of driver incompatibility with latest kernel.
I solved the problem with patched drivers for Bionic because it turns out that that driver is marked EOL for 20.04 fossa.

> For NV4x and G7x GPUs use `nvidia-304` (304.137) End-Of-Life!

So I recommend also for that if you have graphics card of that family to not to use latest Linux.
The latest working for me was kernel 4.15 which comes with Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04. The default kernel if you install 18.04 is 5.4 so it must be downgraded.

Resources for further research was the most helpful here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1737750

Links helped me a lot:

- https://adufray.com/blog/2018/06/02/nvidia-304-127-on-bionic
- https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/4/

to create my own patched binary.
If someone need it without going too much into details - it can be found here
https://sites.google.com/view/tpanj/files/nvidia-legacy

Comment: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142 EOL notice for that GPU

Comment: nice binary! may you do same for 5+?? http://blog.schmorp.de/2019-08-03-nvidia-legacy-304-patch-for-post-50-linux-kernels.html

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1229038/692061 original solution

Comment: I will take a look now

Comment: are you succeded?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

My slowenian is a little rusty, but google told me, that it means:

```
There is no file or directory with this name
```

So my educated guess is, that you did not install the linux headers, or at least not the right ones. I've had that problem several times in debian: my Kernel and the headers were not the same (I still didn't figure out why).

So check your kernel version with `uname -a` and compare them with your linux headers. They must be the same.

Comment: Linux jMacPro 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to get a GeForce 7950GT to work with Ubuntu 20.04. Graphical interface was unusable even upon booting from the live USB.

The weirdest trick made it work for me: (1) change to a non-graphical terminal, (2) login, (3) run `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`. After the process finishes, (4) run `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`.

After these steps, the graphical terminal should work. As I read elsewhere, Ubuntu is technically still using nouveau when I do this (as one may confirm by running `gpu-manager | grep nouveau`). For a reason I ignore, my system just works after I do that without any flickering at all.